# How to create a growing bacterial colony?

Tags: modeling, animation, particles

So, I've been trying to create a short 3D animation of a bacteria dividing|splitting itself multiple times like this

[image]

I adjusted some shape keys for it, but I think it would be too overwhelming to adjust it over and over...

https://gyazo.com/943601d25fe2386b553a701dd7b3b098

I've also tried using the particle system with the molecular script but I still didn't achieve what I expected to, it's sort of making a particle splits into 2, then they split into 4, and it goes on, any possible way to recreate this? A reply would be great!

Comment: I recommend metaballs, but beyond that I’m not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I gave this a try since I think it is a challenging exercise and this is the result:

[image]

I made a base capsule object of 2m long with a shape key that turns it in two parts as the gif you provided, measuring 4m long.

When the shape key reaches 1.0, I hide that object and show another 2 capsules to replace it and start animating their shape key. This could be chained several times and create copies of that group of objects to achieve the desired effect.

I also added a curve modifier to them to make it more organic (even the curve can be animated to improve the cell movement).